# Use of set_timeout with Sublime Text 3 API

Tags: python, settimeout, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am trying to use (as the title says) the
    set_timeout
function of sublime text 3 in a plugin. 
For what I understood, the use of a lambda function is required in many cases. So I tried this simple test :

```
class SetTimeoutTestCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        for x in range(1,10):
            sublime.set_timeout(lambda : print(x), 4000)
```

So I expected that I will have number printed one at a time with a delay of 4 seconds between each. As explained in the Sublime 3 API :

> Runs the callback in the main thread after the given delay (in milliseconds). Callbacks with an equal delay will be run in the order they were added.

But instead I have 9 '9' that are printed after 4 seconds. So all '9' are printed at the same time, based on the first iteration of the loop.
Do you have an idea of what I can do to solve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Edit : I found this which work (well, which print '9' 9 times with 1 second delay between each :

```
class SetTimeoutTestCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        for x in range(1,10):
            sublime.set_timeout(lambda : print(x), x*1000)
```

But on problem remains : it only prints out '9' ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print different numbers change your plugin script on this

```
class SetTimeoutTestCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        for x in range(1,10):
            sublime.set_timeout(lambda x=x: print(x), x*1000)
```

Because all lambda functions refer to the same `x` and when it's executed the `x` value reaches `9`.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks you. In the assignment can we replace by : `lambda y=x: print(y)`

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to understand is that the set_timeout calls return immediately. That is, you are scheduling all of the print functions to be run in 1 second. Not 1 second from each other. Based on your edit, it seems you figured that out, but just thought I would clarify.

As for always printing 9, all of the print statements are referencing the same value. So, even when the first print is scheduled, it references the same x value that you are incrementing. By the time the print actually runs (1 second later), the value of x is 9. Thus, 9 is printed for every scheduled callback.

Hope that clarifies things some.

Comment: OK, for what I understand, the lambda function will take the last value of x as there is no assignment. By doing the assigment the value is replaced in every iteration. Do you have a reference for learning more on this subject ? Thanks =)

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head, though I'm sure they're out there. It's helpful (in general) to understand when things  are passed by reference vs passed by value.